# how to change left border color of the indented UItableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been learning Swift and iOS programming by building a HN reader app. Everything is working so far. But I 'd like to add some features, one of them being displaying a colored left border for each tableview cell. The color depends on the indent level of the cell which is set by manipulating the left margin (heading) NSLayoutConstraint. What I want to achieve looks like something in the picture below.

Any ideas as to what property I could change to get this effect? Thanks and appreciated your help.
[intended effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zncZU.jpg)

Comment: Just make a view that draws a vertical bar and add it to your cell content view. Or even make it the cell background view.

Comment: Thank you. I added an UIView with a vertical bar shape to the left of the cell and set its color based on the indent level and got what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using a custom cell that has a textfield inside, you can add a CALayer, check this code.

```
let border = CALayer()
border.backgroundColor = UIColer.red.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:self.frame.size.height)
yourTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: Thank you. I got what I want from the answer above.